# Do I need both tsconfig type and angular script for Javascript libraries in an Angular project?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I am wondering what is the correct way to load a Javascript library into an angular project. I am currently adding both the dependency and types dependency to the package.json:

```
"@types/jquery": "^3.3.38",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
```

Then in the tsconfig.json adding the types:

```
"types": [
  "jquery"
]
```

Then importing the script into the angular.json:

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
]
```

Are all these steps needed and/or am I missing a step? I expected the typeRoots tag in the tsconfig to automatically find the types and load the scripts. I have also seen javascript libraries not able to find functions from other libraries so is there an additional step to initialize them?

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing for jQuery. I'm not sure why it doesn't get picked up from the root.

Comment: @Brandon I was able to fix that. Apparently the ordering of the scripts matters. They get loaded in the order they appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nothing else to do.
The only thing you may miss is that when you use it in Angular you have to import it from the library with:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

One thing to improve is to change the inclusion of the script with the minified version:

```
"scripts": ["../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"]
```